# php script works when manually run but only partially works as cron job (will not write files to directory)

Tags: php, linux, permissions, cron

I'll start by saying I am very new to linux in general. What I have is a php script I wrote that fetches images from posts on reddit.com hides the post and adds the link to an array, then saves all the images in the array. when I type something like: "php cron.php" as root it runs fine, but whenever crontab runs it the script only hides all the posts but never saves the images. To me it sounds like a problem with permissions by the cron user. Ive been messing with it for hours and recently changed it the www-data user's crontab with: "su -l www-data -c 'crontab -e'" but still no cigar, since its a cron job I suppose its running silently and not giving me any errors. If anyone could show me how to display these messages it would surely help debugging. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're running php cron.php under yourself, but cron works under different user and even if you're trying to run it under www-data it is still different user from yourself

simple solution: check what right has folder where php tries to write, set them to 0777 to test, check if cron script is successful

then you can have different options, like - set folder's owner to cron and set 0755
or move cron user to the same group as you're

Comment: I've also tried chmod on the folders but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly because it seems like that should work, at first I did chmod 777 /media/flashdrive but after reading your comment I realized that command is not recursive and that i need to also do it to the folder within "flashdrive" that i save my gifs to called "gifs" tried it, no luck.

Comment: try to use `chmod -R 0777 /media/flashdriver/...`

Comment: Hmmm, this is all making sense to me but its just not working. Do I need to be a certain user when I'm using chmod? I'm doing everything as root.

Comment: @user2913821 do you have any errors? enable php logging, maybe there you will see something

Comment: Like I said I'm very new and the instructions to do that seem a bit over my head but I can tell you that it should not be an error with the php code. because when i run it as my regular user im running rasbian on a raspberry pi so my "Pi" user I get a permission error printed to the screen as I should, Then on root it runs flawlessly, and when cron does it i get the same result as when Pi runs it (I notice changes on my reddit account but no new files in my gifs folder) the only difference is when cron runs it it doesnt print the errors.

Comment: @user2913821 find you're php.ini file, and set `display_errors=on` , `display_startup_errors=on` , `error_reporting=E_ALL|E_STRICT` , `log_errors=on` , `error_log = /tmp/php_errors.log` after that run script via cron and check error log file

Comment: I did that, let cron run the script, and there is no sign of an error log in /tmp/ so does that mean there where no errors?

Comment: @user2913821 at least it looks so, then you can try to add debug output into some log file in your php file, at least you will know that it called by cron and executed till some stage

Comment: Well I sort of already do know it is being executed and ran until the very last line before it copy's the image from the internet to my local gifs folder because its making changes to my reddit account. So I'm at a loss. with as little as I know about linux it could be a million simple things. thanks for trying!

Comment: @user2913821 if you're using copy function - rewrite it to CURL, you will have more information about problem

Comment: I may have just thought up a work around, might I have my cronjob initiate a bash script which then starts my php script? I don't feel like its an error with the php code since i have a copy on my windows machine and its running fine.

Comment: @user2913821 execution on windows machine doesnt prove that php code is ok :) also there are can be some network issues (closed ports for particular user for example), if you're change copy to CURL you will be able to handle/report this errors

Comment: I don't have 10 reputation so I can't answer my own question yet (that's silly.) so Ill just do so here to keep others from wasting their time. After about a days worth pf googling, and tearing the world apart trying to solve my problem I found that crontab runs the file in the home directory despite being located somewhere else. This broke my php code since it had a relative address to my gifs folder. I solved this problem by simply changing my relative address to an exact address. Hope this helps!